# Getting PermissionError while running python program on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am working with a library called flask-dramatiq and when i execute flask worker command i am getting this error-

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/context.py", line 72, in RLock
    return RLock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 187, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, RECURSIVE_MUTEX, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 59, in __init__
    unlink_now)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: That means that the user that was running this program did not have the permission to do something the program was trying to do. What exactly is unclear?

Comment: I already tried giving it root permission but the problem still presist

Comment: Looks weird, just a thought be useful to check if the folder containing the scripts or the scripts themselves have the correct permissions?

Comment: Tried giving my directory permissions but the command still gives me error. Do you think this can be symlink releated issue?